# How to find out consecutive sequence of numbers in two different vectors in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, pattern-matching

Suppose one vector is x=
[-2    -2    -1    -1    -1    -2    -1    0    5    -1    0    5   -1     0] and other vector is y=[ 2 3 4 5 -1 0 5 -1 0 5 -1]. The two vectors need not to be of same length. I want to find out the similar sequence/pattern of longest consecutive numbers in two vectors using MATLAB? The result should be starting and ending indices of matched pattern in both vectors. For this example: ix=[7 12] and iy=[5 10].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires the Image Processing Toolbox and the Statistics Toolbox. It uses a loop over chunk size:

```
x = [-2 -2 -1 -1 -1 -2 -1 0 5 -1 0 5 -1 0];
y = [ 2 3 4 5 -1 0 5 -1 0 5 -1];
for n = min(numel(x), numel(y)):-1:1; % try sizes in decreasing order
    x_sliding = reshape(im2col(x,[1 n],'sliding'),n,[]).'; % reshape needed for n=1
    y_sliding = reshape(im2col(y,[1 n],'sliding'),n,[]).'; % reshape needed for n=1
    [ind_x, ind_y] = find(pdist2(x_sliding, y_sliding) == 0);
    if ~isempty(ind_x)
        ix_start = ind_x;
        iy_start = ind_y;
        ix_end = ind_x+n-1;
        iy_end = ind_y+n-1;
        break
    end
end
```

The solutions, if they exist, are given in `ix_start`, `ix_end`, `iy_start`, `iy_end`. If there are several solutions of the maximal possible size, the indices of all of them are produced.

Comment: Working fine. Do this method works, in case all numbers in consecutive sequence are not same unlike given example?

Comment: You have not used 'y' anywhere in your solution?

Comment: Plz check minor updation to my question.

Comment: @erbal Sorry, I thought you wanted to longest run of equal values